# Scifi anthology series episode, movie, and book about a man whose dreams change the world

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw a science fiction anthology series episode in which when a man manipulated by a doctor, I think a psychiatrist, slept and dreamed he would wake up to a world affected by what he had dreamed.

When I saw it, I looked it up and found that it was based on a book, and that a movie had also been made based on it.

I cannot remember the names of any of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are, of course referring to "[The Lathe of Heaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lathe_of_Heaven)" by Ursula K. Le Guin.

I'm unaware of an anthologised TV version of the book but there have been two made-for-TV film versions; [The Lathe of Heaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lathe_of_Heaven_%28film%29) (1980) and the similarly titled [Lathe of Heaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lathe_of_Heaven_%28film%29) (2002).

Per Wikipedia;

> "In Portland, Oregon in the near future, George Orr is charged with
>   misuse of multiple prescription medications, which he was taking to
>   keep himself from dreaming; he volunteers for psychiatric care to
>   avoid prosecution, and is assigned to the care of licensed
>   "oneirologist" William Haber. Orr's explanation of his drug abuse is
>   incredible: he has known since age 17 his dreams change reality, and
>   tries to prevent himself from dreaming because he fears their
>   effects."

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are referring to [The Lathe of Heaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lathe_of_Heaven_%28film%29), a film that was based on the 1971 science fiction novel [The Lathe of Heaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lathe_of_Heaven) by Ursula K. Le Guin. In it, a man sleeps, dreams, and awakes to an altered reality that only he recognizes as being altered.