# Summary execution for cancer

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I've been trying to recall the name of a book for years, here and there and not very seriously, but now it's driving me crazy. When I was a freshman in highschool I read a fairly short science fiction novel that left me with a feeling that's really stuck with me, but that I remember almost no concrete details of. I know that it was published quite a while before 1998, my feeling is late 70's or early 80's. The protagonist drifted through worlds, I think, and he likened himself to a jellyfish, it may've been a theme. I do distinctly remember one scene though, where the man is walking on a crowded street, and the police detect that someone has cancer, tracks them down amid the crowd and executes them right there on the street.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57183/scifi-anthology-series-episode-movie-and-book-about-a-man-whose-dreams-change?noredirect=1&lq=1 (film version)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This scene from Ursula K. Le Guin's [*The Lathe of Heaven*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416556966) is a good match:

Ch. 9:

> The crowd bumped around the pair, some stopping to watch, others
>   pressing on toward the Palace of Sport. “This is a Citizen’s Arrest,
>   passersby please take notice!” the tall man was saying in a piercing,
>   nervous tenor. “This man, Harvey T. Gonno, is ill with an incurable
>   malignant abdominal cancer but has concealed his whereabouts from the
>   authorities and continues to live with his wife. My name is Ernest
>   Ringo Marin, of 2624287 South West Eastwood Drive, Sunny Slopes
>   Subdivision, Greater Portland. Are there ten witnesses?” One of the
>   witnesses helped hold the feebly struggling criminal, while Ernest
>   Ringo Marin counted heads. Orr escaped, pushing head-down through the
>   crowd, before Marin administered euthanasia with the hypodermic gun
>   worn by all adult citizens who had earned their Civic Responsibility
>   Certificate. He himself wore one. It was a legal obligation.

The main character doesn't move through worlds, rather he edits the world when he dreams. But there are frequent sea-life analogies, especially sea turtles and jellyfish.

Ch. 1 (opening paragraphs):

> Current-borne, wave-flung, tugged hugely by the whole might of ocean,
>   the jellyfish drifts in the tidal abyss. The light shines through it,
>   and the dark enters it. Borne, flung, tugged from anywhere to
>   anywhere, for in the deep sea there is no compass but nearer and
>   farther, higher and lower, the jellyfish hangs and sways; pulses move
>   slight and quick within it, as the vast diurnal pulses beat in the
>   moondriven sea. Hanging, swaying, pulsing, the most vulnerable and
>   insubstantial creature, it has for its defense the violence and power
>   of the whole ocean, to which it has entrusted its being, its going,
>   and its will.
>
> What will the creature made all of seadrift do on the dry sand of
>   daylight; what will the mind do, each morning, waking?

It's a fairly short novel first published in 1971.